# Update the SubTitle of a listview without refreshing in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

At start, I load data from the database that populates the ListView. These data is displayed on the ListView title and subtitle. When a user taps on one of the items on the list, a `showModalBottomSheet` popups with fields to update the list(index). This update is carried out successfully but on the close of the `showModalBottomSheet`, the values on each ListView item refreshes to default (data from database).

Please, how can I update the ListView items without the ListView refreshing to initial data value?

```
 Widget _buildSubjects(BuildContext context, int index) {

  response = getFieldData(_snapshot!.data[index]);

return ListTile(
  trailing: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      _snapshot!.data[index]['name']
                          .toString()
                          .toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: _scoreForm,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        scoreFields(_snapshot!.data[index]),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (!_scoreForm.currentState!.validate())
                              return;
                            _scoreForm.currentState!.save();

                             setState(() {
                                    response = "New Value";
                              });
                            
                            //close bottomsheet
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Save Score"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
  title: Text(
    _snapshot!.data[index]['name'].toString().toUpperCase(),
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    ),
  ),
  subtitle: Text(
    response,
  ),
  onTap: () {},
);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: @Dev I have added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap your ListTile with ValueListenableBuilder like below:

```
ValueNotifier<bool> newData = ValueNotifier(false);

 ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          valueListenable: newData,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return ListTile(
  trailing: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add), //... rest of your code
```

and instead of calling

```
setState(() {
        response = "New Value";
});
```

call below without setState

```
response = "New Value";
newData.value = !newData.value;
```

so now the state of the ListTile will be updated and no need to setState for the complete listview.

Answer (score 0):

To update the data in Listtile(title and subtitle) you need to use Stream and Streambuilder which will update the data based on stream change from your database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).